# Bootstrap 4 column order not working on mobile

Tags: html, css, layout, bootstrap-4

I want to use order-width-pos from bootstrap 4 but for some reason its not working on the mobile view. It works fine up until the point where it snaps to the mobile viewsize and I dont know why.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zRpQeG

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<section>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row ">
      
      <div class="col-xl-3 col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 order-xs-last order-md-last order-lg-first box">
        <h1>col 1</h1>
        <hr/>
      </div>

      <div class=" col-xl-3 col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6 order-xs-first order-lg-first box">
        <h1>Col 2</h1>
        <hr/>
        </div>

      <div class=" col-xl-6 col-md-12 order-md-first order-xs-first order-lg-last box">
        <h1>Col 3</h1>
        <hr/>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no more `xs` with Bootsrtrap V4 so remove it and it will work.

The new version of Bootstrap is mobile first so no prefix (`sm`, `md`, `lg`) is equivalent to **extra-small** device. If you specifiy `sm` it is equivalent to **small** device and up.

As you can read [in the documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/):

> Grid breakpoints are based on minimum width media queries, meaning
>   they apply to that **one breakpoint and all those above** it (e.g.,
>   .col-sm-4 applies to small, medium, large, and extra large devices,
>   but not the first xs breakpoint)

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<section>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row ">
      
      <div class="col-xl-3 col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 order-last order-md-last order-lg-first box">
        <h1>col 1</h1>
        <hr/>
      </div>

      <div class=" col-xl-3 col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6 order-first order-lg-first box">
        <h1>Col 2</h1>
        <hr/>
        </div>

      <div class=" col-xl-6 col-md-12 order-md-first order-first order-lg-last box">
        <h1>Col 3</h1>
        <hr/>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Thanks didnt know that, probably read over it again and again..